# What counts as "not killing humans"?

Tags: achievements, prey

There is achievement in Prey (2017) called "Do not harm" (or something like this), and you need to finish game without killing a single person during your playthrough. But what counts as killing human? There are at least several situations I'm concerned in:

- > breeding mimics - you are not killing person, you just let mimics to attack it;
- > When human, being controlled by typhon, has his head exploded (I'm still not sure, what causes this)
- > When false cook quest ends, and this person triggers utilization grenade on himself.

So, can someone answer me, which of situations above may lead to achievement failure?

Comment: Last one does not count as killing human, confirmed by myself

Comment: Probably "that guy" in the test chamber counts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for what **doesn't** count as killing a human:

- Mind-controlled enemies exploding when they approach you do not count as kills
- Phantoms with a name does not count as a kill.
- Ignoring Quests that require you to save someone do not count as you killing them

Some **tips** to get this achievement:

- Take care with recyclers and explosions.
- Remember to save any human just in case, as it is very possible this will impact the achievement
- Use the Stun Gun to render humans unconscious
- Periodically check the "humans killed" stat to see if you killed someone and you need to reload (or start again in the worst cases)

Some people get a single human kill when they enter the **Crew Quarters** near the Telepath (on the same zone).

I hope you get it eventually, it's not as hard as it seems.

Comment: actually, the mind-controlled humans *do* count if you kill them, just not if the Typhons detonates them (they will exploded either way I think), but you can avoid them and try and take out the controller.

Comment: Well, I've got it already several days ago.

Comment: Congratulations!!

Comment: @Yorik If you stun the mind-controlled humans before they explode, they'll drop unconscious and unharmed. If you're OCD like me, you'll waste time dragging each one to one of the crew rooms and lock them in.

Comment: what about the console with the time limit on the bridge?  I'm hoping for that achievement on this run and just discovered this time limit.

Comment: "Humans killed" doesn't seem to be on the stats list any more, only on the ending screen.

Comment: @Yorik the one in the Treatment Centre exploded in my face, and that didn't count as a kill.